# Hilbert class field of $ \Bbb{Q}( \sqrt{-5})$

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, algebraic-number-theory, class-field-theory, ramification

I want to prove $ \Bbb{Q}( \sqrt{-1},\sqrt{-5})$ is Hilbert class field of $ \Bbb{Q}( \sqrt{-5})$.

Let $H$ be Hilbert class field of $ \Bbb{Q}( \sqrt{-5})$.
I know already from elliptic curve theory that $[H: \Bbb{Q}( \sqrt{-5})]=2$.

Thus, I need to prove here is

> $ \Bbb{Q}( \sqrt{-1},\sqrt{-5})$ is unramified at any prime of $\Bbb{Q}( \sqrt{-5})$.

How can I formally prove this ? Thank you for your kind help in advance.

Comment: Sorry title and content differed, it was just typo. The base field is  $ \Bbb{Q}( \sqrt{-5})$ whose class number is $2$.

Comment: Hint: show that this extension is generated by an element which is a root of a monic polynomial which is separable mod $2$.

Comment: You go on local field $ \Bbb{Q}_p( \sqrt{-5}, \sqrt{-1})/\Bbb{Q}_p(\sqrt{-1})$ ? Why $mod2$ appears ?

Comment: What is the discriminant of $x^2+1$? So at what *finite* primes can $H/\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{-5})$ be ramified? (there is a conceptual difficulty with ramification at infinite places in class field theory, but here it is not present)

Comment: Discriminant is $2^45^2$ and primes which ramify are $(2)$ and $(5)$, right ?

Comment: The discriminant of $x^2+1$ is $(i-(-i))^2 = -4$. So $x^2+1$ has a non-zero discriminant in $\Bbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]/(p)[x]$ (thus separable) for each $p\ne 2$ and hence $H/\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{-5})$ is unramified away from the primes above $2$.

Comment: Thank you reuns, sorry to bother, but could you tell me what is your definition of discriminant  here ?

Comment: As you mention "elliptic curve theory", it's worth pointing out that you can also compute $H$ by just adjoining the $j$-invariants of all elliptic curves with CM by $\Bbb Z[\sqrt{-5}]$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $K = \mathbf Q(\sqrt{-5})$ and $L = K(i)$, so $L$ has the quadratic subfields $M = \mathbf Q(i)$, $K = \mathbf Q(\sqrt{-5})$, and $N = \mathbf Q(\sqrt{5})$. Since $M$ is unramified away from $2$ and $N$ is unramified away from $5$, $K/\mathbf Q$ is unramified away from $2$ and $5$. (I am not considering archimedean ramification.) Thus $K/\mathbf Q(i)$ is unramified away from $(1+i)$, $(1+2i)$, and $(1-2i)$. How do $(1+i)$, $(1+2i)$, and $(1-2i)$ decompose in $K$?

How $(1+i)\mathcal O_K$ factors: in $\mathcal O_M = \mathbf Z[i]$ we have $(2) = (1+i)^2$ and in $\mathcal O_N = \mathbf Z[(1+\sqrt{5})/2]$ the ideal $(2)$ is prime, so $2\mathcal O_K = \mathfrak p^2$ where ${\rm N}(\mathfrak p) = 4$. Thus $((1+i)\mathcal O_K)^2 = \mathfrak p^2$, so $(1+i)\mathcal O_K = \mathfrak p$: $K$ is unramified at $(1+i)$.

How $(1+2i)\mathcal O_K$ factors: in $\mathcal O_M = \mathbf Z[i]$ we have $(5) = (1+2i)(1-2i)$ and in $\mathcal O_N = \mathbf Z[(1+\sqrt{5})/2]$ we have $(5) = (\sqrt{5})^2$, so $5\mathcal O_K = \mathfrak q\mathfrak q'$ where ${\rm N}(\mathfrak q) = {\rm N}(\mathfrak q') = 5$. Thus $(1+2i)\mathcal O_K (1-2i)\mathcal O_K = \mathfrak q\mathfrak q'$, so the ideals $(1+2i)\mathcal O_K$ and $(1-2i)\mathcal O_K$ are both prime: $K$ is unramified at $(1+2i)$ and $(1-2i)$.